# jQuery DataTable plugin: custom column option & updating default option at run time

Tags: jquery, plugins, datatable

I'm writing a small custom plugin for the jQuery DataTable where it's enabled with the standard table level option. I'm having two issues:

1. Being able to add a custom column definition option that the plugin would then retrieve
2. Set a standard DataTable column option to a new value determined at run time.

For example, I'd define my table like so:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    myPlugin:   true,
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'col1',
        myPluginOption: ['optionVal1', 'optionVal2']
      },
      .
      .
      .
    ]
} );
```

Then in the plugin I'd like to attach a listener to the 'dt.init' event and in it do something like this:

```
...
_dtInit: function() {
   this.dt.columns().every(function() {
        //1. retrieve the value of my custom option
        var myOptions = this.myPluginOption; //or this.myPluginOption() ?
        ...
        //2. set a default column option to a new value that 
        //wasn't known at initial definition (e.g.: dataOrder)
        this.dataOrder = [newInt1, newInt2];

   });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way making use of the fact that when a listener is added to a DT event settings get passed to the listener function.

We need to use original/old style option names for this however. Attribute names are mapped to the old ones by DT internally and only exist in the settings object in their prior option name state. I.e.: orderData option exists in settings object as aDataSort. Here's full parameter conversion reference: https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

```
...
_dtInit: function(e, settings) {
   $.each(settings.aoColumns, function(index, column) {
       //1. retrieve the value of my custom option

       var myOptions = column.myPluginOption;

       ...

       //2. set a default column option to a new value that 
       //wasn't known at initial definition (e.g.: dataOrder)
       //*** Using old option name for dataOrder here:

       this.aDataSort = [newInt1, newInt2]
   });
}
```

- Note, step 2 example probably isn't the best here as updating sortable order will cause the table to re-sort already loaded data and re-draw. This would be better suited in the preInit listener before the data is loaded.